# Focus back to textbox on blur event angular

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

**View:**

```
   <label class="item item-input">
       <input type="text" ng-model="scan.text" placeholder="Scan here" ng-enter="scanBarcode2(scan)" ng-focus="hideKey()">
       <span>{{scantext.text}}</span>
   </label>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('RollCallScan2Ctrl', function($scope,$stateParams, Api, $cordovaBarcodeScanner,$filter,$ionicPopup) {

    var a=[], b={};
    $scope.empdata = a;    

    $scope.scan = {text: ""};   


})
```

I want to set focus on textbox, when view is loaded and whenever focus is off from it or user touches anywhere in screen. I need to focus back to textbox.

Comment: have you tried ng-blur?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using 'ng-blur' directive in Angular. I have created a sample plnkr with setTimeout to see the focus which is going back to textbox when the focus is out

http://plnkr.co/edit/JNfYmL0Bk7pcJXQdQWWN?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module("focusApp", [])
.controller("focusController", function($scope) {
  document.getElementById('sampleText').focus();
  $scope.focusTextBox = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('sampleText').focus();
    }, 100);
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="focusApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="focusController">
    <input type="text" id="sampleText" placeholder="Focussed text box" ng-blur="focusTextBox()"><br /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text box to test Focus">
  </body>

</html>
```